# How do i make a Vimeo API call with a uri?

Tags: api, video, uri, vimeo

I want to use the Vimeo API to search for videos with specific tags. To do this I know I have to use the [Vimeo's Advanced API](https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced) to make a [vimeo.search](https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/methods/vimeo.videos.search) call. But how do I actually do that via a uri? I also know that with using the Advanced API I will need to have OAuth oauth_consumer_key and oauth_signature.But how would I pass this information in from the uri?

If I do get the data from the API then I will use PHP to process it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps
[**like this**](http://hurl.it/hurls/ac6ab0045daf805e4442aaa18d79942f8e03688e)?

```
GET /api/v2/video/6238577.xml HTTP/1.1
Host: vimeo.com
Accept: */*
```